# Why rename imports to same name?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

In the asyncio `__init__.py` script, all of the imports are renamed with the same name. Please provide an example of how and why this can ever be useful?

```
from asyncio.coroutines import (
    coroutine as coroutine,
    iscoroutinefunction as iscoroutinefunction,
    iscoroutine as iscoroutine,
)
```